# how to pass multiple services in controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a service called authService. I call it from the Logincontroller as follows :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController',function($q, $scope, $location,$routeParams, $window, authService) {//some code here});
```

this works fine.

Now I have another service called regService which is like :

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('regService ', function ($window, $q, $rootScope) {//some code here});
```

Now in LoginController how do I call functions from regService ?

Comment: Just pass `regService` to `LoginController` function like any other parameter.

Comment: `angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController',function($q, $scope, $location,$routeParams, $window, authService, regService) { /* ... */});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both existing answers are technically correct, but if you decide to minify/uglify your code anytime in the future, those solutions will eventually break.

To prevent this, John Papas AngularJS style guide favors the use of the `$inject` service in [Y091](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y091) like so :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController', LoginCtrl);

LoginCtrl.$inject = ['$q', '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$window', 'authService', 'regService'];

function LoginCtrl($q, $scope, $location, $routeParams, $window, authService, regService) {
  //some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like authService, you just need to add regService. AngularJS will automatically bind the service based on name. You might want to understand more about Dependency Injection - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('LoginController',function($q, $scope, $location,$routeParams, $window, authService, regService) {//some code here});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('LoginController', function($q, $scope, $location, $routeParams, $window, authService, regService) {
});
```